# Azure Blockchain Service node properties

Tags: transactions, private-blockchain, cryptography, microsoft-azure, websocket

What exactly are Access key 1, Access key 2, Member account, Web socket, DNS, creater account, etc. of a node in Azure Blockchain Service? I am getting confused as to what are these. Also what are the public key and private key of a node from encryption perspective?